# My simple android app keeps crashing

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple android app and keeps on crashing when I launch it. the emulator says "appname keeps stopping". I did not edit the default code in the activity class. My layout xml is bellow:

```
 <RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>
<TextView 
  android:id="@+id/lblName"
  android:text="Name"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  />
<EditText 
  android:id="@+id/txtName"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@id/lblName"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:inputType="text"
  />
 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:layout_below="@id/txtName"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  >
  <Button
  android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"      
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Submit"
  ></Button>
  <Button
  android:id="@+id/btnCancel"      
  android:layout_weight="1"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="Cancel"
  ></Button>
  </LinearLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post yout logcat or error you getting

Comment: post stacktrace atleast

Comment: Show us the  the log error  and activity code

Comment: @admire Chikudo, You forgot to give layout_width to Button. set android:layout_width="wrap_content" to each button that you have used in your layout.

Answer (score 2):

Buttons inside the `LinearLayout` should have the attribute `android:layout_width="0dp"`

Answer (score 0):

I have fix your layout that add android:weightSum="1" on LinearLayout and width on button to 0 dp

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:text="Name" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/lblName"
    android:inputType="text" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/txtName"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:text="Cancel" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Post your java code for this activity as well :)